# Cross Compiling for arm

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling

I am writing a c++ application and trying to cross compile for arm:
    sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi

However in the /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include directory I find no c++ directory. Can someone tell me where to find it?

Comment: You have to install the g++ packages also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install C++ compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Comment: Add the same problem for aarch64. I thought that installing gcc would include g++...doh!